# Android Checkbox error "on a null object reference"

Tags: android, checkbox, reference, null

I tried to make a checkbox that when it is checked it will strikethrough text field elements in the listview. I'm pretty sure that I did everything correctly including set up the ID for the checkbox in XML and declared it on the class that I wanna use but I still get the Null object error.

I have looked through all the question and answer all over this topic, I also tried them all but I still get an error. Could someone please help me identify where an error might be.

Thank you so much in advance for any help =)

**Class file**

```
package com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping;

import...

public class MainListView extends AppCompatActivity {

    //================DATABASE=====================//
    private ShoppingListDatabase databaseConnection;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public ListView ListView_mainListView;
    public ArrayList<ShoppingList> lists;
    public AppCompatCheckBox checkBox_doneCheck;
    public TextView textView_listname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //================DATABASE Connection================//
        databaseConnection = new ShoppingListDatabase(this);
        db = databaseConnection.open();

        //important!!!
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list_view);
        getLists();

    }

    public void getLists(){

      ....
        ******Original here, but I delete by acident******
        checkBox_doneCheck = findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doneCheck);


        checkBox_doneCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (checkBox_doneCheck.isChecked()) {
                    textView_listname.setPaintFlags(textView_listname.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                else{

                    textView_listname.setPaintFlags(textView_listname.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**XML file**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox_doneCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

**Error log**

```
Process: com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping, PID: 19958
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping/com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping.MainListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping.MainListView.getLists(MainListView.java:107)
        at com.puyakul.prin.psychic_shopping.MainListView.onCreate(MainListView.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: you forget to find id of checkbox in your class.

Comment: you have register check box or layout in activity. setContantView and findviewid for check box.

Comment: he told he is sure he did everything correctly including set up the ID for the checkbox in XML and declared it on the class.. :(

Comment: so sorry my bad, I deleted some of the `checkBox_doneCheck = findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doneCheck)` by accident while try to shorten the text =(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the association between the `xml` and `java` code.
Add this line:

```
checkBox_doneCheck = findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doneCheck)
```

Thats why you are having the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I add it but still error.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `checkBox_doneCheck`, try this instead in `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list_view);
checkBox_doneCheck = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doneCheck);
getLists();
```

You may also want to do something similar with those variables:

- `ListView_mainListView`
- `textView_listnameist item`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply
I add the line but still facing the error